# Change \topsep in a list without packages

Tags: lists, lengths

Consider this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\topsep}{3\baselineskip}
%\setlength{\partopsep}{3\baselineskip}

\hrulefill

\begin{enumerate}
\itemsep=20pt
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I know there is a possibility to change `\itemsep` with `enumitem` package, but I expect there is a method to change it locally without need of packages.

Why changing the length `\topsep` has no effect on vertical space before and after items unlike `\partopsep` length ( remove % before `\setlength{\partopsep}{3\baselineskip}`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `\topsep` is defined by the class in an internal macro called `\@listi`, `\@listii`,`\@listiii`, etc, depending on the nesting depth of the list. This macro is called at the `\begin{list}`. On the other hand, `\partopsep` is defined globally in the class.

So you would have to change those macros, depending on the nesting depth. For example:

```
\makeatletter
\let\orig@listi\@listi
\def\@listi{\orig@listi\topsep=3\baselineskip}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Sorry, Piet, I wasn't able to get it running.  I added it in the preamble, as well as in the list itself.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @SalimBou You have to add these lines immediately before the `enumerate` environment, not to the preamble. If you need them more frequently, wrap it into a new environment. When you put the patch into the preamble, it will be overwritten with every size changing command, like `\normalsize` issued at the beginning of the document.

Comment: @SalimBou Alternatively, replace `\@listi` by `\@listI` (capital i at the end) in the patch, then it might work when you put it into the preamble. But this will affect all list environments (in normal size), which might not be what you want.

Comment: I can embed changes of `\@listi` in a macro  like this `\def\ctopsep#1{
\let\orig@listi\@listi
\def\@listi{\orig@listi\topsep=#1}}` then I can use it with `\ctopsep{3\baselineskip}` when I need it