# How to set \topsep=0pt on the latex standard list implementation inside an environment?

Tags: macros, lists, environments, lengths, xpatch

## Two attempts which not worked

Herein there are 2 examples which did not work. Each attempt has written over it `% Not works`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english}{babel}
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{abntex2}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
style=abnt,
language=english,
backref=true,
backend=biber,
citecounter=true
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\makeatletter 
\let\orig@listi\@listi
\def\@listi{\orig@listi\topsep=0pt} % Not works
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    Test
    \begin{citacao}\setlength{\topsep}{0pt} % Not works
        Test
    \end{citacao}
    Test

\end{document}
```

The `citacao` environment is implemented at:

1. https://github.com/abntex/abntex2/blob/8f2109ac2ef986b15d97d0bfc489b251918f1761/tex/latex/abntex2/abntex2.cls#L961-L978

   ```
   \newenvironment*{citacao}[1][default]{%
      \list{}%
      \ABNTEXfontereduzida%
      \addtolength{\leftskip}{\ABNTEXcitacaorecuo}%
      \item[]%
      \begin{SingleSpace}%
      \ifthenelse{\not\equal{#1}{default}}{\itshape\selectlanguage{#1}}{}%
    }{%
      \end{SingleSpace}%
      \endlist}%
   % ---
   ```

## Two attempts which worked

Herein there are 2 examples which did worked.The first is by renewing the environment, the other opening the abntex2 files on my computer and changing the implementation.

1. I could just change its implementation adding `{\topsep=0pt}` as in:

   ```
   \newenvironment*{citacao}[1][default]{%
      \list{}{\topsep=0pt}%
      \ABNTEXfontereduzida%
      \addtolength{\leftskip}{\ABNTEXcitacaorecuo}%
      \item[]%
      \begin{SingleSpace}%
      \ifthenelse{\not\equal{#1}{default}}{\itshape\selectlanguage{#1}}{}%
    }{%
      \end{SingleSpace}%
      \endlist}%
   ```
2. Or renew the environment in my document as in:

   ```
   \renewenvironment*{citacao}[1][default]{%
      \list{}{\topsep=0pt}%
      \ABNTEXfontereduzida%
      \addtolength{\leftskip}{\ABNTEXcitacaorecuo}%
      \item[]%
      \begin{SingleSpace}%
      \ifthenelse{\not\equal{#1}{default}}{\itshape\selectlanguage{#1}}{}%
    }{%
      \end{SingleSpace}%
      \endlist}%
   ```

## The question

But I would like to not hardly copy their implementation, neither am interested in doing a pull request for adding `{\topsep=0pt}`. May I do something like this bellow, patching the environment?

```
\pretocmd{\citacao}{\let\oldtopsep\topsep \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\citacaoend}{\let\topsep\oldtopsep}{}{}
```

Why this is not on my code on the beginning of the post?

Because I could not make it work patching it manually, by adding `\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}`, therefore loading `xpatch` will do no help if I do not know how to patch. None of these worked:

```
% First attempt
\makeatletter 
\let\orig@listi\@listi
\def\@listi{\orig@listi\topsep=0pt} % Not works
\makeatother

...
    % Second attempt
    \begin{citacao}\setlength{\topsep}{0pt} % Not works
        Test
    \end{citacao}
```

---

Related questions:

1. [Change \topsep in a list without packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346443/change-topsep-in-a-list-without-packages)
2. [Adding vertical space (\vspace) around custom environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156986/adding-vertical-space-vspace-around-custom-environment)
3. [\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean (and what about the bottom)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/topsep-itemsep-partopsep-and-parsep-what-does-each-of-them-mean-and-wha)

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? Can you put your fragments together into a single, (non-)compilable example?

Comment: @cfr, I provided 2 examples which work, 1 by renewing the environment, the other opening the abntex2 files on my computer and changing the implementation. I also provided 2 examples which did not work. They are the first code on the post, and each attempt has written over it `% Not works`. I will update the post with this information.

Comment: But what does 'not working' mean? You don't say. Do you get an error? Do you get output you don't expect?

Comment: You need to patch it and not just append to the command. That is, you need `\patchcmd` and search for `\list{}` and replace with the line you want there instead.

Comment: @cfr, with not work I mean the `\topsep=0pt` is not applied, i.e., it is ignored. I also just tried to do `\xpatchcmd{\citacao}{\list{}}{\list{}{\topsep=0pt}}{}{}` and it worked, but if some day they decide to add some argument to the `\citation` `\list{}{}`, it would stop working. That is why I thought about trying to use `\xapptocmd` and `\pretocmd`.

Comment: Yes, but it can't work that way because it is added at the wrong time. It needs to come  after `\list{}` and before `\item`. Use the final arguments to trigger an error or warning in case an update stops it working.

Comment: So the only way to change the latex standard `\list` `\topsep=0pt` is on the list declaration itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is `\topsep` setting hard-coded in standard list environments (itemize, enumerate, description), from inside such environment it is too late to correct the top use, and changing `\topsep` will not influence the bottom use.

Assuming one can not customize directly the `\list` usage, one can attempt this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\setlength{\topsep}{40pt}% useless

BEFORE

\begin{itemize}
\item \the\topsep
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

AFTER

\color{blue}

BEFORE

\begin{itemize}\kern-\topsep
\makeatletter\advance\@topsepadd-\topsep\makeatother
\item \the\topsep
\item A
\item B
\item C
\end{itemize}

AFTER

\end{document}
```

[image]