# Why \parsep and \itemsep are not working on my standard list implementation?

Tags: spacing, lists, environments

This spacing should be bigger for the values of 100pt I added:

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english}{babel}
\documentclass[
10pt,
a5paper,
twoside
]{abntex2}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewenvironment*{citacao}[1][default]{%
   \list{}{%
   \topsep=0pt%
   \itemsep=100pt%
   \parsep=100pt}%
   \ABNTEXfontereduzida%
   \addtolength{\leftskip}{\ABNTEXcitacaorecuo}%
   \item[]%
   \begin{SingleSpace}%
   \ifthenelse{\not\equal{#1}{default}}{\itshape\selectlanguage{#1}}{}%
 }{%
   \end{SingleSpace}%
   \endlist}%

% \makeatletter
% \let\orig@listi\@listi
% \def\@listi{\orig@listi\itemsep=100pt}
% \makeatother

\begin{document}

    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test
    \begin{citacao}
        Test
    \end{citacao}
    Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test

\end{document}
```

1. [Change \topsep in a list without packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346443/change-topsep-in-a-list-without-packages)
2. [Adding vertical space (\vspace) around custom environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156986/adding-vertical-space-vspace-around-custom-environment)

Comment: The first item is affected by `\topsep`, which you've set to `0pt`.

Comment: You only have one item in your list environment example.

Comment: I reallly hope the 100pt is just for an example. As jfbu and Werner said, they *are* working. Just add some paragraphs inside the quote, and obviously add some space with `\topsep`. Your idea about automatic italics for foreign quotes may be nice, but the user should be able to figure it out by himself.